Question on upper bound of rank of a matrix
I was working on this problem I found online (no solution available online).
A and B are 2 matrices. Rank of A is 1 and rank of (A+B) is 3. What is the maximum possible rank of B?
My progress:
It is evident:

$ Rank(A+B) <= Rank(A) + Rank(B) $

So lower bound on rank(B) is 2.
But how do I get the upper bound?
My progress:
Rank of A+B is 3. In echelon form, A will have only one non-zero row. If the sum of that row with a linearly independent row of B produces a zero row, then we have reduction of rank by 1 in going from B to A+B, which means that the rank of B could have been at most 4.
In general, I could come up with:

$ Rank(A+B) >= |Rank(B) - Rank(A)| $

Is this correct? I could not find the equation anywhere, so I have a feeling I might be missing out on something.
Some insight would be much appreciated!

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

If $\text{Rank}A+B) \le \text{Rank}(A) + \text{Rank}B)$ for all $A$ and $B$, then $\text{Rank}(B) = \text{Rank}(A+B-A) \le \ldots$

But rank of (A+B) and (B-A) are not the same, right?
Using your relation,
$ Rank(B) <= Rank(A) + Rank(B-A) $
So, $ Rank(B) <= 1 + Rank(B-A) $
